# Easily browsable atlas of current climate normals for Europe

Tags: climate

I'm looking for an end-user friendly atlas of climate normals for Europe.

CM-SAF have a [climate atlas](http://www.eumetsat.int/website/home/Images/ImageLibrary/DAT_2266050.html) but this is for particular months.  KNMI have a [climate explorer](https://climexp.knmi.nl/plot_atlas_form.py) but it is specifically about climate change.  What I'm looking for is like what UK Met Office have [for the UK](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/public/weather/climate), or what exists in the Dutch school atlas [Bosatlas](http://www.bosatlas.nl/wps/portal/nubosatlas).  Of course, this can be constructed relatively easily from publicly available reanalysis data, but does any online interface exist that is relatively easy to use for end users?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such easy-to-browse climate data atlas for Europe so far. There are only seperate atlases offered by severel countries, e.g. [Germany](http://www.dwd.de/EN/climate_environment/climateatlas/climateatlas_node.html).